# Spark - Extract line after String match and save it in ArrayList

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to spark and trying to extract a line which contains "Subject:" and save it in an arraylist. I am not facing any error but the array list is empty. Can you please guide me where am i going wrong? or the best way to do this?

```
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction;
public final class extractSubject {

public static void main(String[] args) {



    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("JavaBookExample");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    JavaRDD<String> sample = sc.textFile("/Users/Desktop/sample.txt");
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    sample.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>(){

                    public void call(String line) {

                       if (line.contains("Subject:")) {
                           System.out.println(line);
                           list.add(line);
                       }
                   }}
    );

    System.out.println(list);
    sc.stop();
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind that Spark applications run distributed and in parallel. Therefore you cannot modify variables outside of functions that are executed by Spark.

Instead you need to return a result from these functions. In your case you need `flatMap` (instead of `foreach` that has no result), which concatenates collections that are returned as result of your function.

If a line matches a list that contains the matching line is returned, otherwise you return an empty list.

To print the data in the `main` function, you first have to gather the possibly distributed data in your master node, by calling `collect()`.

Here an example:

```
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;

public final class extractSubject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("JavaBookExample");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

        //JavaRDD<String> sample = sc.textFile("/Users/Desktop/sample.txt");
        JavaRDD<String> sample = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList("Subject: first",
                                                              "nothing here",
                                                              "Subject: second",
                                                              "dummy"));

        JavaRDD<String> subjectLinesRdd = sample.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
            public Iterable<String> call(String line) {
                if (line.contains("Subject:")) {
                    return Collections.singletonList(line);  // line matches → return list with the line as its only element
                } else {
                    return Collections.emptyList();  // ignore line → return empty list
                }
            }
        });

        List<String> subjectLines = subjectLinesRdd.collect();  // collect values from Spark workers
        System.out.println(subjectLines);  // → "[Subject: first, Subject: second]"

        sc.stop();
    }
}
```